# Getting Web data through Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python Selenium. I am trying to get the web data table into python dataframe.

Website details: https://reports.dbtfert.nic.in/mfmsReports/displayPortal
 -> Company Sales -> Ist Point Sales(All Product Groups) -> Put start and end dates -> Click show reports

The web page table look like [image: Page Screen shot]

The code I have written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='E:/Softwares/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://reports.dbtfert.nic.in/mfmsReports/displayPortal')
elem1 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Company Sales')
elem1.click()
elem2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Ist Point Sales(All Product Groups)')
elem2.click()

from_date = browser.find_element_by_name('parameterFromDate')
from_date.clear()
from_date.send_keys('01/08/2019')

to_date = browser.find_element_by_name('parameterToDate')
to_date.clear()
to_date.send_keys('31/08/2019')

to_date.submit()

table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/table[3]')
table_text = table.text
table2 = table_text.splitlines()
```

The above code gives me a table content in the list form. Below is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This is in the list form. I want to convert it to dataframe like the webpage table.

How to convert it to dataframe with exact column headers and format?

Please help.

Comment: Don't have selenium at hand, you could try along the line `pd.read_html(browser.page_source, ...)`

Comment: Thanks. As per your suggestion I have updated the code as 

`table = pd.read_html(browser.page_source)[4];
table.columns = table.iloc[0];
table = table.drop(table.index[0])` 
and it worked perfectly as per my need.

Comment: Hi @jf328, I am facing another issue. Now I am fetching the below content from the same website: _Company Sales -> Company Sales to Dealer
-> Select State and District -> Select Start and End date
-> At max we can extract 1 month data_. Here the table we got is a scrolling table . It is not captured by `pd.read_html(browser.page_source)` command. Please help.

Comment: It's inside an iframe. You need to switch the browser object to inside that frame. Google `selenium switch iframe` should get you there

Comment: btw, `pd.read_html` has a `header` argument to deal with your `table.columns` manipulation.

Comment: btw 2, IMO it's better to use the `match` argument in `pd.read_html` to drill down to the specific table, rather than indexing, as that might change. In all, try make full use of the function arguments.